# How to create a post-init container in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to create a redis cluster on K8s. I need a sidecar container to create the cluster after the required number of redis containers are online.

I've got 2 containers, `redis` and a sidecar. I'm running them in a `statefulset` with 6 replicas. I need the sidecar container to run just once for each replica then terminate. It's doing that, but K8s keeps rerunning the sidecar.

I've tried setting a `restartPolicy` at the container level, but it's invalid. It seems K8s only supports this at the pod level. I can't use this though because I want the `redis` container to be restarted, just not the sidecar.

Is there anything like a `post-init container`? My sidecar needs to run **after** the main `redis` container to make it join the cluster. So an `init container` is no use.

What's the best way to solve this with K8s 1.6?

Comment: Would a [`postStart Container hook`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/#container-hooks) help? It's not another container though; it's a "command" (e.g. a script) to be executed inside a container's namespaces and cgroups.

Comment: I guess I could use that if there's nothing better, but that means I'll have to add my management scripts to the main redis container instead of keeping them in a sidecar, which I'd prefer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better answer is to just make the sidecar enter an infinite sleep loop. If it never exits it'll never keep on being restarted. Resource limits can be used to ensure there's minimal impact on the cluster.

Comment: This could work but only if what you're doing in your sidecar is safe to be re-run since there's no guarantee that the container WILL NOT be restarted. If you want to ensure so, you might consider writing an empty file in the pod (The file only survives as long as the pod, so you know that it has only been run once).

Answer (score 8):

I advise you to use Kubernetes Jobs:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/

This kind of Job will keep running until it is completed once. In this job you could try detecting if all the required nodes are available in order to form the cluster.

Answer (score 3):

Adding `postStart` as an optional answer to this problem:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/attach-handler-lifecycle-event/#define-poststart-and-prestop-handlers

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: lifecycle-demo
spec:
  containers:
  - name: lifecycle-demo-container
    image: nginx
    lifecycle:
      postStart:
        exec:
          command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo Hello from the postStart handler > /usr/share/message"]
```